# How to check if a java method returns null without having to run it twice

Tags: java

I have this situation many times in my code,

I have a method for example such as:

```
private Object doSomething(){
//Do something
doSomething ? return Object : return null;
}
```

This is just an example, then in the main body of my code I need to check that this doesn't return null before I do something else. For example:

```
if(doSomething() != null){

Object object = doSomething();
```

From a performance perspective this method is being asked to run twice, once to check it doesn't return null and next to assign the new variable as long as it returns a valid object.

Is there a way to develop this code where this double running doesn't have to take place. Bearing in mind that the check to make sure the object is valid is important in the code.

Comment: Reverse it. First assign the result to `object`, then check whether `object` is null.

Comment: How about storing the result of `doSomething()` in a variable ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just reverse the process. First assign the result of that call to a variable, then check if the variable is `null`.

```
Object object = doSomething();
if (object != null) {
    // do whatever with object
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

It is worth noting that the problem with multiple calls to `doSomething` may not only be a performance penalty. It could also be a problem if:

1. `doSomething` has side effects, for example if it inserts a row in a database, in which case calling it twice will insert two rows.
2. `doSomething` depends on some external state which may change between invocations.

Comment: Yes I understand, sometimes the object returned is a string and I need to check it is not null before I try to set it to a String text = doSomething() or else I get the null pointer, but I guess in this case do I need to be returning ""; an empty string and then the check can be (text.length() >0) Is this normal practice?

Comment: `null` is a thing. Empty string is another thing. Depends on what `doSomething` actually... well, does. If it makes sense for it to return an empty string, return an empty string (for example if the method returns the string between two indexes and the indexes happen to coincide). If it makes sense to return null, return null. Anyway a `String` can be null, so there's no problem if you do `String str = doSomething(); if (str == null)........`

Answer (score 2):

Consider using Optional rather than returning null (introduced with Java 8).

```
public Optional<Object> doSomething() {
  return Optional.ofNullable(someData);
}
```

When invoked, you have an Optional reference that may (or may not) have contents.

```
Optional<Object> maybeSomething = doSomething();
if (maybeSomething.isPresent()) {
  Object someData = maybeSomething.get();
  System.out.println("SomeData = "+someData);
}
```

Optional blends well with lambda so you could rewrite that as..

```
Optional<Object> maybeSomething = doSomething();
maybeSomething.ifPresent(someData ->  System.out.println("SomeData = " + someData);
```

or, if you don't need to do more work with `someData` you could even do

```
doSomething().ifPresent(someData -> System.out.println("SomeData = " + someData);
```